# qt detect mouse click duration while button pressed

Tags: qt, qt5

I'd like to shutdown system if a button pressed more than 3 seconds.
how can I detect click duration while the button is pressed?
I can do it using pressed() and released() but not at press time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a QTimer:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPushButton button("Press me");

    QTimer timer;
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    timer.setInterval(3 * 1000);

    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::pressed, &timer, [&timer](){
        timer.start();
    });
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::released, &timer, [&timer](){
        timer.stop();
    });
    QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [](){
        qDebug() << "shutdown";
    });

    button.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```